# AEM rollout configuration not working for blueprint to live copy flow triggered from code

Tags: aem, jcr

I have a setup with blueprints and live copies but I am experiencing some weird behavior.

***Example 1:***

- Edit the title of a page (blueprint) using the UI -> title gets also set in the live copy

***Example 2:***

- Edit the title of a page (blueprint) using code -> title gets set in the blueprint but **DOES NOT** get set in the live copy

Code:

```
Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

Resource brandPageResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/content/platform-blueprints/company/nl/brands/439");
Page brandPage =  brandPageResource.adaptTo(Page.class);

Resource brandPageContentResource = brandPage.getContentResource();
Node brandPageContentNode = brandPageContentResource.adaptTo(Node.class);

try {
    brandPageContentNode.setProperty(JCR_TITLE, "NEW-TITLE-FROM-ENDPOINT");
} catch (RepositoryException e) {
    LOG.error("Error initializing components", e.getMessage(), e);
}

session.save();
```

Does somebody know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change a node's property the surrounding page will not get an update on its cq:lastModified property and the page will not be marked as changed in the UI as well.

You could use PageManager.touch() to update the cq:lastModified and cq:lastModifiedBy properties of the page.

Using Resources instead of Nodes might also do the trick - but I am not sure about that one.

Comment: You are right, using the UI or Code has no impact on the cq:lastModified property, I checked it. But why does it works using the UI than?

Comment: I am also not sure how you would edit properties of a page using a Resource.

Comment: Because then AEM internal processes take care of that... and keep everything up to date.

Comment: Use ModifiableValueMap map = resolver.getResource(path).adaptTo(ModifiableValueMap.class); to get a map that is modifiable.. resolver.commit(); is then saving the data.

Comment: I was wrong ui changes DO update the lastModified property

Comment: And I did not see the "UI" in "using the UI or code"... ;-) sorry for that